# how to use ajax to stop refreshing of entire web page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

I am struggling a bit to apply ajax to my current code. I am new and not too sure how to go about it.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
<script>

function openTab(NetworkTabs,elmnt,color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  $.ajax()
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(NetworkTabs).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, in which way would us use AJAX? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({ url:"test.php",
        type:"post",//Get,POST or PUT
        data:{value='abc'},
        success:function(data)
         {
         //Your code here
         }
        error:function()
         {

         }
   })
```

Comment: i tried that but I am no longer able to see the content on webpage :/

Comment: I just  gave you a sample jquery ajax structure. you have to replace 'test.php' by your request handling code